# Running word count on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

MY HADOOP started on single node .
But while running word count programm it shows following error.
What may be the problem ?

```
 hduser@reshmi-Inspiron-1545:~/hadoop-1.0.4$hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount 
 /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/dft /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/dft-output 
 /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004':command not found
 /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
 /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar: line 2: `)CA META-INF/��PK'
 hduser@reshmi-Inspiron-1545:~/hadoop-1.0.4$ ^C
 hduser@reshmi-Inspiron-1545:~/hadoop-1.0.4$ cd ..
 hduser@reshmi-Inspiron-1545:~$ /hadoop-1.0.4  hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount 
 /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/dft /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/dft-output 
 bash: /hadoop-1.0.4: No such file or directory
 hduser@reshmi-Inspiron-1545:~$ ^C
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the hadoop script in the bin folder and the jar sub command to invoke your job, try this:

```
hduser@reshmi-Inspiron-1545:~$ cd ~/hadoop-1.0.4
hduser@reshmi-Inspiron-1545:~/hadoop-1.0.4$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar \
       wordcount /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/dft \
       /home/hduser/hadoop-1.0.4/dft-output
```

I'm also assuming from your input and output paths that your hadoop is configured for local mode (as the paths are local paths: /home/hduser)